# Create video from picture frames?

Tags: video

How can i create a video out of picture frames?
So let's say i have about 60 images, and i want to create a video out of them.
The format of the video doesn't matter.
What language is the best for this idea? 
Java, c#, or objective c?

Comment: For questions like this, you'll get better answers if you provide more details about your platform and what you are trying to do.  Is this part of a program, or is the program only for creating video from frames?  Is this Windows, where DirectShow is available, or something else?  The more specifics you provide, the better people can help you out.

Comment: I am trying to make a program that creates videos out of an array of images. Platform can be windows or mac.
I cannot do this with command line, the program suppose to be receiving images through the socket.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest is just to use [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) on the [commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299196/how-to-write-frames-to-a-video-file) 
Otherwise [OpenCv](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) is pretty easy, or you can use the ffmpeg library

Comment: See also docs: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to achieve this is using mencoder

i wrote a blog post a while ago that shows how
http://www.local-guru.net/blog/2010/01/12/making-a-video-from-single-frames

Answer (score 0):

If you have Matlab available, you can use its movie creation features as well.